Pine Script complex request multi timeframe
I known the principles of the security requests with higher timeframes, but struggling on two requests.
The Standard for open/close and HA works perfect:
[m_open_conf,m_open_real,m_close_conf,m_close_real] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", [open[1],open,close[1],close], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
[m_ha_open_conf,m_ha_open_real,m_ha_close_conf,m_ha_close_real] = request.security(ha_ticker, "M", [open[1],open,close[1],close], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

How can I do this for the following two cases? I have already tried a lot of possibilities, but none of them has worked.
1.
curve = ta.wma(ta.roc(source, longRoCLength) + ta.roc(source, shortRoCLength), wmaLength)




esma(source, length)=>
    s = ta.sma(source, length))
    e = ta.ema(source, length))
    po_exp ? e : s

I have tried for example this for the two cases:
m_po_short_conf = ta.sma(m_close_conf, 5)
m_po_long_conf = ta.sma(m_close_conf, 25)

m_curve_real = ta.wma(ta.roc(m_close_real, longRoCLength) + ta.roc(m_close_real, shortRoCLength), wmaLength)
m_curve_conf = ta.wma(ta.roc(m_close_conf, longRoCLength) + ta.roc(m_close_conf, shortRoCLength), wmaLength)


Where is your try with the security()?

Sorry, you are right i have missed this. Here is the try:
m_curve_conf = ta.wma(ta.roc(m_close_conf, longRoCLength) + ta.roc(m_close_conf, shortRoCLength), wmaLength)

And the following:
m_po_short_conf = ta.sma(m_close_conf, 5)
m_po_long_conf = ta.sma(m_close_conf, 25)


Try request.security with any function, like this:
m_po_short_conf = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M",
                  ta.sma(close, 5)[1],
                  lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)  //No repaint

